# Daily count per date from counters in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, counter

I have a query is ms-access:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MSC_cdr_counters2.[datetime1],"DD/MM/YYYY") AS date1,       MSC_cdr_counters2.[type], sum(MSC_cdr_counters2.[counter]) AS counter
FROM MSC_cdr_counters2
WHERE (MSC_cdr_counters2.[datetime1] BETWEEN #10/01/2016# AND #11/01/2016 00:01:00#)
AND (MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] = "MOC"
OR MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] = "FORW"
OR MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] = "SMMO"
OR MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] = "SOC"
OR MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] = "PBXO")
AND MSC_cdr_counters2.[datetime1] LIKE "*2016 0:00:0*"
GROUP BY MSC_cdr_counters2.[datetime1], MSC_cdr_counters2.[type] ;
```

Result (a part of it):

```
date1       type    counter
04.10.2016  FORW    6173453
04.10.2016  MOC 563216323
04.10.2016  PBXO    19
04.10.2016  SMMO    186950644
04.10.2016  SOC 17377649
04.10.2016  FORW    43247163
04.10.2016  MOC 3026671916
04.10.2016  PBXO    17812373
04.10.2016  SMMO    704397148
04.10.2016  SOC 1690090
05.10.2016  FORW    6173593
05.10.2016  MOC 563216323
05.10.2016  PBXO    19
05.10.2016  SMMO    186950644
05.10.2016  SOC 17399117
05.10.2016  FORW    43261775
05.10.2016  MOC 3027868092
05.10.2016  PBXO    17812373
05.10.2016  SMMO    704782312
05.10.2016  SOC 1694332
06.10.2016  FORW    6173752
06.10.2016  MOC 563216323
06.10.2016  PBXO    19
06.10.2016  SMMO    186950644
06.10.2016  SOC 17421247
06.10.2016  FORW    43276252
06.10.2016  MOC 3029133560
06.10.2016  PBXO    17812373
06.10.2016  SMMO    705187581
06.10.2016  SOC 1698475
```

But I want output:

```
    Date        Type    Increase in counters per day vs next day
    4.10.2016   FORW    14752
    4.10.2016   MOC 1196176
    4.10.2016   PBXO    0
    4.10.2016   SMMO    385164
    4.10.2016   SOC 25710
    5.10.2016   FORW    14636
    5.10.2016   MOC 1265468
    5.10.2016   PBXO    0
    5.10.2016   SMMO    405269
    5.10.2016   SOC 26273
    6.10.2016   FORW    14308
    6.10.2016   MOC 1237012
    6.10.2016   PBXO    0
    6.10.2016   SMMO    390327
    6.10.2016   SOC 25520
```

I have been googling a lot but I can't seem to find a way how to query the daily count per type (5.10 counter - 4.10 counter, 6.10 counter - 5.10 counter etc). My sql skills are not that good. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're after.  You have three fields in your **MSC_cdr_counters2** table: **datetime1**, **type** and **counter**.  For each **type** in your table, you want the sum of the **counter** field grouped by **datetime1** and show the difference between the current date and the previous date?  Is it for all types, or just those you've used in your `WHERE` clause?  Are all dates represented, or are weekends/bank holidays missed?

Comment: The period is a full month (so that means all the days in the month). In the query I have : BETWEEN #10/01/2016# AND #11/01/2016 00:01:00# . Only those types as seen in the query i am interested in. Yes i want counter value to be summed by date and show the difference with the next day counter for the same type.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting duplicate rows for the same date and type?  It looks like there must be two different time entries on the same day to give the results you are getting.  You'll need logic to combine them to a single value.  I set up this query to do that and saved it as MSC_CDR_Summary

```
SELECT Year([DateTime1]) AS Yr, 
     Month([DateTime1]) AS Mn, 
     Day([DateTime1]) as Dy,
     First(MSC_CDR_Counter2.DateTime1) AS DateTime1, 
     MSC_CDR_Counter2.Type,
     Sum(MSC_CDR_Counter2.Counter) AS [Counter]
FROM MSC_CDR_Counter2
GROUP BY Year([DateTime1]), Month([DateTime1]), MSC_CDR_Counter2.Type
ORDER BY First(MSC_CDR_Counter2.DateTime1), MSC_CDR_Counter2.Type;
```

With this summary, I created the following to give the change between days:

```
SELECT MSC_CDR_Summary.DateTime1,
      MSC_CDR_Summary.Type,
      MSC_CDR_Summary.Counter,
      (select first(Counter) from MSC_CDR_Summary T where T.Type=MSC_CDR_Summary.Type and T.DateTime1>MSC_CDR_Summary.DateTime1) AS [Next],
      [Next]-[Counter] AS Change
FROM MSC_CDR_Summary;
```

This uses a subquery to find the next date of the same type and get that day's counter.  If it is more clear, this could be pulled out as a separate query.

It seems to me that you would want the change from day 4 to day 5 to be reported in day 5, but I obviously don't know your full requirements.